# javascript - Google Maps Full Screen Button Not Working ( Non-google maps app )

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, fullscreen

As shown below, beides the '+' icon is the full screen button.

[image: Map Issue]

When clicked on it, it does not go full screen.

I tried basic jQuery :

```
 $("#fullScreen-btn").css({height: 100%, width: 100%});
```

This does not seem to work.

I need it to work like we press F11 on browsers, it must go full screen on mobile (not the google maps app)

Can anyone help me out here ?

Comment: Is this a react native app running on android?
And you want it to be able to go to full screen hiding the android UI?

Comment: I need it to go fullscreen but it is a javascript-jquery based app and it is not a react native app.

Comment: share more code.

Comment: @AshishBahl check the answer and let me know if you have any problem

Answer (score 8):

In order to make a Mobile Browser visible in full screen mode, you should use the [`requestFullscreen()`](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/fullscreen/)

Add an event listener to the button dynamically when it gets loaded as

```
button.addEventListener("click",function(){
      document.body.requestFullscreen();
});
```

Or

```
button.addEventListener("click",function(){
         document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
});
```

Works for Chrome for android.

Also many browser for Computers also have this ability.

Read more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API)

Answer (score 4):

Your jQuery needs correction - you missed the quotes, try this:

```
$("#fullScreen-elm").css({"height": "100%", "width": "100%"});
```

and moreover you need to update this css for the screen element you want to resize and not the fullscreen button.

And yes, `Element.requestFullscreen()` is definitely an other option refer [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API)

Comment: I would like to have comments on downvotes. Please explain your(whomsoever) reason to downvote the answer. It will help me in improving my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I calculated the height separately to achieve the results. Tested in android device.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let height = $(document).height();
  $('.fullscreen').on('click', function() {
    $('iframe').css({
      height: height,
      width: '100%'
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.fullscreen {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>
  <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d423283.3363121453!2d-118.69191670818714!3d34.020750397391296!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x80c2c75ddc27da13%3A0xe22fdf6f254608f4!2sLos+Angeles%2C+CA%2C+USA!5e0!3m2!1sen!2srw!4v1499159650271"
    width="250" height="250" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <div class="container">
    <input type="button" name="fullscreen" value="fullscreen" class="fullscreen" />
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can activate full screen mode using JavaScript without jQuery.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>Full Screen Test</title>
</head>

<body id="body">
    <h1>test</h1>

    <script>
    var elem = document.getElementById("body");

    elem.onclick = function() {
        req = elem.requestFullScreen || elem.webkitRequestFullScreen || elem.mozRequestFullScreen;
        req.call(elem);
    }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

One thing that is important to note, you can only request full screen mode  when a user performs an action (e.g. a click). You can't request full screen mode without a user action<sup>[[1](https://github.com/private-face/jquery.fullscreen)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode#When_a_fullscreen_request_fails)</sup> (e.g. on page load).

Here is a cross browser function to toggle full screen mode ([as obtained from the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode#Toggling_fullscreen_mode)):

```
function toggleFullScreen() {
  if (!document.fullscreenElement &&    // alternative standard method
      !document.mozFullScreenElement && !document.webkitFullscreenElement && !document.msFullscreenElement ) {  // current working methods
    if (document.documentElement.requestFullscreen) {
      document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen) {
      document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
    }
  } else {
    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
      document.exitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
      document.msExitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
      document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
      document.webkitExitFullscreen();
    }
  }
}
```

For more information, check out the [MDN page on full screen APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode).

If you need a plugin that supports versions of IE prior to IE11 (IE8-10), take a look at [jQuery.fullscreen](https://github.com/private-face/jquery.fullscreen). IE did not support this feature natively until [IE11](http://caniuse.com/#search=fullscreen).